# React / JS - How to track REST API changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way to track REST API changes in JS, especialy in React JS.

I want to have handler (functiom) who will be fired on REST API changes, live?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? For example, you want to track when a new endpoint is added?

Comment: Something like https://socket.io/? See their example in the main page with the tweets bein updated.